# http://api.rubyonrails.org/ clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, documentation, clone

I'd like to build a website very similar to http://api.rubyonrails.org/
is there any gem I can use for that? or anything else I can easily reuse? 
thanks 
zb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the sdoc gem. The sdoc gem was developed for http://railsapi.com. (And is also used on http://api.rubyonrails.org/)

The source itself lives on github at https://github.com/voloko/sdoc/